# WPF / Silverlight flowchart designer

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, workflow, flowchart

Anybody knows an open source product/framework, based in the MS stack, that allows modeling workflows (flowchart)?

It should allow:
- Drag and drop different node styles;
- Define properties for those nodes;
- Connect the nodes;
- Export to xml (non mandatory).

Any help is appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a great series on CodeProject related to this -

WPF Diagram Designer - Part 4

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx

You may not find all the features(like property editing) but you can easily implement them.

One more is available here -

http://flowpad.codeplex.com/

Comment: Very good examples, thank you! Like you said, they are not complete as per my requirements, but can definitely be extended.

Comment: Yes, I have also created a designer(similar to VS) based on Diagram designer having property grid. You can get a free WPF property grid here - http://wpg.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider using Windows Workflow, where the flowchart programming model is directly suppoed?